# Python: Store rotation / normal in bezier curve point?

Tags: python, bezier-curves

Still trying to visualize a game file format in Blender, I think I reached a limit of what I can do with Blender Bezier Curves.

The game file format defines the coordinates of the curve point and the two handles. It additionally, however, defines a rotation of the curve point, basically a normal, because it needs to move and rotate objects along the path the curve forms.

Is it possible to store a normal in a Bezier Curve Point?

- I didn't find anything like a normal / rotation for bezier curve points in the documentation.
- Also, curves don't seem to support custom data layers like with the BMesh API where I could at least store the original normal information. Also it would be hard to edit those normals then visually.
- I think it would be a monstrous task for someone who has never worked with the Blender C(++) codebase to add a new object type supporting that, or is it possible to relatively "easily" add normals to curve points or derive a new curve type from the existing one, just adding this information and keeping big parts of the base curve class?

Comment: You can always have a parallel data structure to store this additional information and go from it to the curve (and from the curve to it) using a dictionary

Comment: I thought about that, but what when the user deletes curve points? I can only identify them by index correctly AFAIK, and then the mappings get all messed up.

Comment: the user has the ability to delete it in your game while you don't know it ?

Comment: No. For each point, I need to remember additional data (2 floats, and a rotation). If I store that in a parallel data structure it will desync as soon as a vertex in the curve is deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bezier curve objects can store a property called [tilt](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/curves/introduction.html#active-spline).
It is basically a per point rotation value or normal that controls it's twisting on a per.vertex basis.

It can be set through the UI in edit mode under the *Properties Shelf > Transform > Tilt* or through the [Python API](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.BezierSplinePoint.html#bpy.types.BezierSplinePoint.tilt) with `bpy.types.BezierSplinePoint.tilt`

[image: Bezier Curve Tilt]

As far asI know curves don't support arbitrary data layers per vertex like BMesh does, but I may be wrong.

Comment: That looks quite promising. I just have to find out how to calculate the tilt angle from an XYZ normal rotation the data I got gives me. And yeah, there are no custom data layers according to the docs, which is another issue since I need to store 2 game specific floats for each point...