# How to fix twisting in beveled curve?

Tags: bezier-curves, bevel

I have a simple bezier curve made up basic angles. When i try to bevel it and give it some thickness, what should be a cylinder becomes twisted and warped. I have attached some pictures. How can I fix the twists and warps?

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/59153/python-store-rotation-normal-in-bezier-curve-point and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56396/logarithmic-curve-with-spiralling-cross-section or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65633/how-can-i-create-twisted-geometry . Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66353/how-to-make-beveled-90-degree-corners-on-a-curve-better