# Adding a "Super Elevation" or Twist to a road

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to figure out how to twist or add a slight rotation to an object at a transition that I can control.

Currently I have half of a road drawn, that's being mirrored, following the array length of a bezier curve, as well as following the curve deformation of said bezier curve.  I want to know if I can add slight twists at certain bends of the road or if it's even possible before I apply the Mirror modifier.

Current sample road looks like so:
[image]

[image]

Whereas an engineered road would have the road twist to match the curve of the road as seen between these two cross sections (program: Microstation Select Series 2):

A "Normal" Cross Section of a road:
[image]

A "Super Elevated" Section of a road:
[image]

Once I get the twisting and rotating down, I'm going to tackle trying to make proper intersection, but I want to make sure this is feasible before I go down this route (I'm sure it is but I want the most painless path possible).

**EDIT:**
The tilt command as suggested by Duarte Farrajota Ramos is close to what I'm looking for but it doesn't solve my problem, but it's something I didn't know about and glad it was brought up.

[image]

I don't know if there's some plugin or additional tools out there that will help but to give a better understanding of what I'm shooting for here's a series of images.  I currently have the left side of the road controlled by a percentage line.  That point or line is referencing the center of the road so that if the red line is below 0, it slopes downwards, but if it's above 0, it slopes upwards. (please excuse my atrocious mouse spelling)

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm sorry for asking something so incredibly specific.  I may just have to do it manually per every section.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Store rotation / normal in bezier curve point?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/59153/python-store-rotation-normal-in-bezier-curve-point)

Answer (score 1):

I would use an array modifier and a curve modifier on a small portion of the road object. So you model a short piece of road and mirror it and then you add an array modifier to it and create a new bezier curve object. Then you add a curve modifier to your road piece and choose the bezier curve as the curve your curved modifier will use to draw the array on.

Comment: You can then go into edit mode of the bezier curve and add new vertices with e for extrude and tilt the vertices as you like. You can also change the scale of your array object by pressing ctrl + a and then moving your mouse. Or just write it by hand in the properties tab (n) on the side.