# When using curves to create ('square') piping, how do I get nice corners?

Tags: bezier-curves

I've set up a curve where at some points 3 or even 4 curves meet at a junction:

[image]

When I try to convert this to an actual shape:

[image]

I get both:

- really ugly corners,
- 'twisted' tubing: the square tubing before and after a junction do not align nicely.

So, my two (related) questions are:

**a)** how can I create the intended shape with corners that line up nicely and?
**b)** how can I how can I control the rotation/orientation of the tubing along the curve?

Are curves maybe the wrong tool for this job?

Comment: Probably the curve isn't the best choice. You should try the skin or the wireframe modifier. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/skin.html https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/wireframe.html

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53475 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66353 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/59153

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the linked questions handle more than two curves coming together at a junction.